# Want to convert Web To Lead automatically into contact and send Email

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service, web2lead

I'm creating a registration page in my site, and use Web To Lead.

I want to Convert automatically that web to lead into Contact and also send Email to the user who register on site.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) for more info on lead conversion in Apex. Once covert process is complete you can write sendemail method to send email.